# Why does this code add an extra zero to my number?

Tags: c++

The following code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool qualities(double number){
    //function qualities, irrelevant to question
}

int main(){
    double pandigital = 123456789;
    double sum = 0;
    string strpan = to_string(pandigital);
    while (next_permutation(strpan.begin(), strpan.end())){
        cout << strpan << endl;
        if (qualities(pandigital)){
            sum += pandigital;
        }
        next_permutation(strpan.begin(), strpan.end());
        break;
    }
    cout << "sum is " << sum << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

has the following problems beginning at this piece of code

```
double pandigital = 123456789;
double sum = 0;
string strpan = to_string(pandigital);
while (next_permutation(strpan.begin(), strpan.end())){
    cout << strpan << endl;
```

The problem is strpan has an extra zero appended to it, which is an error. If I add a zero to pandigital so we have `1234567890`, it will still append an extra zero.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you're converting these numbers to a string, and then concating the strings

Comment: I am converting the number to a string, permutating it, and (then later) converting back to an integer. The break statement is temporary and will be removed when the program is finished.

Comment: Since `pandigital` does not change in your code `qualities(pandigital)` will always evaluate to the same value. So you can take that out of the `while` loop.

Comment: What is the actual output that you think is wrong? What is the output you are expecting, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: Also you are calling `next_permutation` twice which is probably wrong.

Comment: @MariusBancila: unless `qualities()` uses a global variable to maintain state between calls, and thus can return a different value each time it is called.

Comment: @DonLarynx "converting back to an integer" if it suppose to be an integer why do you use `double`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero comes from `std::to_string` converting a `double` to `string`: rather than producing `"123456789"`, it makes `"123456789.0"`.

To fix this problem, declare `pandigital` as `int`, or add a cast when converting it to a `string`:

```
string strpan = to_string((int)pandigital);
```

With this issue out of the way, you have another fix to make: each iteration of your `while` loop calls `next_permutation` twice - once in the header of the loop, and once in the body. You should remove the invocation that you perform in the body of the loop.

Finally, recall that in order to go through all possible permutations the initial call of `next_permutation` should be made when the range is sorted. It is not a problem for your number, because the digits are arranged in ascending order, but it may become an issue if you start with a different number.